# Oracle - Move all tables and reclaim free space

Tags: oracle

I have this query:

```
select file_id, block_id first_block, block_id+blocks-1 last_block,
segment_name
from dba_extents
where tablespace_name = 'USERS'
union all
select file_id, block_id, block_id+blocks-1, 'free'
from dba_free_space
where tablespace_name = 'USERS'
order by file_id, first_block DESC;
```

It shows lot of "free" segments in between. There are lot of tables which are coming in between.

I move the tables using:

```
Alter table table_name move;
```

I have 2000 such tables. Is there a way on how I can move it altogether so I can reclaim all the free space from the tablespace?

Comment: Free segments will be reused as tables grow; are you sure it's necessary to reclaim that space - it won't just be reused later anyway?

Comment: @AlexPoole - yes, I want to free up space on my tablespace.

Comment: article how to reclaim space from AskTom (dated 2006) 
https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:54178027703899

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To achieve your goal you have to move all objects in the tablespace, not just tables. 
At least you have to move tables and then rebuild all their indexes because when you move a table all indexes built on this table are invalidated.
You can not move all tables all together but you can obtain all commands in the following way:

```
 select 'alter table ' ||table_name ||' move;'
 from dba_tables where tablespace_name = 'YOURTABLESPACENAME';
```

To rebuild indexes:

```
select 'alter index ' ||index_name ||' rebuild;'
 from dba_indexes where tablespace_name = 'YOURTABLESPACENAME' and status <>'VALID';
```

**Be careful**: this procedure is not complete, you can have indexes of different kind.

**Note**: to obtain best results you should move objects in a different tablespace.

A simpler approach can be the one explained [here](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_table_shrink_space_command.htm): this article describe how to use the shrink command against Oracle database tables to reclaim wated space.

If you want a detailed procedure give me the result of the following query:

```
select distinct segment_type from  dba_segments where tablespace_name='YOURTABLESPACENAME';
```

Comment: It's an old answer, but it's necessary shrink all segments to adjust the high water mark before to move in the same tablespace?

Comment: Hello, no it is not necessary